# Flutter always show a popup "appname would like to paste from appname" when paste textfield

Tags: ios, flutter, paste

Can anyone help me? I have a new issue when I update to iOS 16 on my device.

When using TextField, iOS will request paste permission when the user initiates the paste. But it seems that active pasting shouldn't need to request Clipboard permissions. It's a user action. I think it does not need a request to paste. How can I avoid it or solve this problem?

This is GitHub issue I submitted.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/122360#issuecomment-1463114422

I create a Flutter project and add simple text filed to new application and build it. When I copy and paste, iOS will request paste permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iphone 16 then please read it : [link](https://9to5mac.com/2022/06/06/ios-16-permission-copy-paste-between-apps/)

Comment: No way to just ask permission once?

Comment: Your app is third party for apple , you have give permission anyone and everytime in 16